how to make search submit button goto a directory with search keyword
Please i have a website the search directory is https://website.org/search/keyword
example if i type john inn search box the submit directory will be "https://website.org/search/john"
so looking for a way to do the search box in html form that will use the directory with any keyword search input

Is that literally your website, or just an example domain? If the latter, there is literally a domain called example.com (and org, net, edu) for these purposes. If that is your site, you can ignore this.

You can use location.href = 'https://website.org/search/' + encodeURIComponent(keyword)
Add the following JS code somewhere after your search form


document.querySelector(".search-form").addEventListener('submit', function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var value = event.target.querySelector("[name=search]").value
  if (!value) {
    return
  }

  var url = "https://example.com/search/keyword/" + encodeURIComponent(value)
  console.log("redirecting to " + url)

  window.location = url

})
<form class="search-form">
  <input name="search">
  <button>submit</button>
</form>



